# I have to click button twice for submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I face remote validation problem. when i click on submit button without focus on textbox then It's call remote ajax  for validation and when i pressed second time submit button then it will be submited the form. **It will not work on same click. If i focus in both textbox and click on submit then it's working fine.**

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){

        if($('#add_sub_seva_form').valid())
        {

            if($("#hid_sub_head_id").val()==$("#hid_head_id").val()){
                $("#add_sub_seva_form .alert-danger").html("Head Name and Sub Head Name should not be same.");
                $("#add_sub_seva_form .alert-danger").show();
                $("#add_sub_seva_form .alert-danger").delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            sub_length=$(".e_sub_head").length; 
            if(sub_length>0){
                for(var i=2;i<sub_length+2;i++){
                    if($("#hid_sub_head_id_"+i).val()=="")
                    {
                        $("#add_sub_seva_form .alert-danger").html("Please Enter Sub Head Name "+i);
                        $("#add_sub_seva_form .alert-danger").show();
                        $("#add_sub_seva_form .alert-danger").delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
//                        alert("Please Enter Sub Head Name "+i);
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            var msg=confirm('Are you Sure?');
            if(msg===true){
                $('#add_sub_seva_form').submit();
            }
            else{
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        else{
            e.preventDefault();
        }

});

 $("#add_sub_seva_form").validate({

       rules:{
           seva_eng:{
               required:true,
               remote: {
                    url: "check-seva.php",
                    type: "post", data: {
                        hid_seva_eng: function() {
                            return $('#hid_seva_eng').val();
                        }
                    }
                }    
           },
           seva_guj:{
               required:true,
               remote: {
                    url: "check-seva.php",
                    type: "post", data: {
                        hid_seva_guj: function() {
                            return $('#hid_seva_guj').val();
                        }
                    }
                }
           },
           event_name:{
               required:true
           },
           head_id:{
               hid_head:true
           },
           sub_head_id:{
               hid_sub_head:true
           }
       },
       messages:{
           seva_eng:{
               required:'Please Enter Seva Name(Eng.)',
               remote:'Seva Name is already exist'
           },
           seva_guj:{
               required:'Please Enter Seva Name(Guj.)',
               remote:'Seva Name is already exist'
           },
           event_name:'Please Select Event Name'
       }
    });
```

Comment: What says the debug on firebug ?

Comment: No Errors/warnings. It's call Remote file check-seva.php on first click.

Comment: Have you put breakpoints on the function you wrote here ? to see if the code gets into the `if($('#add_sub_seva_form').valid())`, and into the `if(msg===true){` ?

Comment: I put alert box before submit the form. alert open on first click but not submit the form.

Comment: you mean you added an alert() in the `if(msg===true){`, the alert is triggered, but not the submit ??

Comment: Right !! Alert is open but form stillnot submit on first click

Comment: So can you add the html code please, near the submit button ? (in your question, not in comments)

Answer (score 0):

I make some temporary solution on window load I focus on textbox.

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').focus();  
};
```

It is tricky solution. it is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

`onfocusout` will remove the focus from the textbox and will allow the form to be submitted with the first click. I had the same issue and resolved it by adding the following to my validate:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  onfocusout: false
});
```

See more at https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question and flag for undeletion.